# format my returned xml response string in new format

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have returned the following String strFees720

which equals :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Fees720>
        <errorNode>
            <errorCode>0</errorCode>
            <errorMsg/>
            <errorSev/>
        </errorNode>
        <forwardScroll>       0093101200001117                0</forwardScroll>
        <backwardScroll>                                        </backwardScroll>
        <Field name="ACCID"><Value>93101200001034</Value></Field>
        <Field name="FPERIOD"><Value>2C</Value></Field>
        <Field name="STDATE"><Value>13 DEC 2012</Value></Field>
        <Field name="ENDATE"><Value>13 DEC 2012</Value></Field>
        <Field name="ADVDATE"><Value>19 DEC 2012</Value></Field>
        <Field name="DBDATE"><Value> F40LA1C   </Value></Field>
        <Field name="SNAME"><Value>N SINGLETON JG</Value></Field>
        <Field name="ACDESC"><Value>OVERDRAFT AAA</Value></Field>
        <Field name="TOTFEES"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="DISCOUNT"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="NETFEES"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="CLRD_BAL"><Value>93101200001034</Value></Field>
        <Field name="ALLOW_RTE"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="DISC_RTE"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="ALLOW_TOT"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="PCODE"><Value>0000000</Value></Field>
        <Field name="DRILLNSC"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="DIALOG"><Value>9</Value></Field>
        <Field name="NUMLINES"><Value>1</Value></Field>
        <Field name="TOTLINES"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        <Field name="BPCUST"><Value>P</Value></Field>
        <Field name="NFEE_EXPDTE"><Value></Value></Field>
        <FEEDATA>
            <Field name="FCODE"><Value></Value></Field>
            <Field name="FEEDETS"><Value></Value></Field>
            <Field name="CHRG_TYPE"><Value></Value></Field>
            <Field name="DCODE"><Value></Value></Field>
            <Field name="VOLUME"><Value>0</Value></Field>
            <Field name="RATE"><Value>0</Value></Field>
            <Field name="TOTAL"><Value>0</Value></Field>
            <Field name="DRILL"><Value></Value></Field>
        </FEEDATA>
        <GROSSNETFEES>
            <Field name="FQUARTER"><Value>06 DEC 12    12 DEC 12</Value></Field>
            <Field name="GRSFEE"><Value>611960</Value></Field>
            <Field name="NFEE"><Value>611960</Value></Field>
            <Field name="FEEDISC"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        </GROSSNETFEES>
        <GROSSNETFEES>
            <Field name="FQUARTER"><Value>01 DEC 12    05 DEC 12</Value></Field>
            <Field name="GRSFEE"><Value>64850</Value></Field>
            <Field name="NFEE"><Value>64850</Value></Field>
            <Field name="FEEDISC"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        </GROSSNETFEES>
        <GROSSNETFEES>
            <Field name="FQUARTER"><Value>08 NOV 12    30 NOV 12</Value></Field>
            <Field name="GRSFEE"><Value>15866</Value></Field>
            <Field name="NFEE"><Value>15866</Value></Field>
            <Field name="FEEDISC"><Value>0</Value></Field>
        </GROSSNETFEES>
        <GROSSNETFEES>
            <Field name="FQUARTER"><Value>01 NOV 12    07 NOV 12</Value></Field>
            <Field name="GRSFEE"><Value>636</Value></Field>
            <Field name="NFEE"><Value>616</Value></Field>
            <Field name="FEEDISC"><Value>20</Value></Field>
        </GROSSNETFEES>
        <Field name="TOTGRSFEE"><Value>693312</Value></Field>
        <Field name="TOTNETFEE"><Value>693292</Value></Field>
    </Fees720>
</Response>
```

I would like to transform this xml string response into a new xml string

as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Fees720>
        <errorNode>
            <errorCode>0</errorCode>
            <errorMsg/>
            <errorSev/>
        </errorNode>
        <forwardScroll>       0093101200001117                0</forwardScroll>
        <backwardScroll>                                        </backwardScroll>
        <accid>93101200001034</accid>
        <fperiod>2C</fperiod>
        <stdate>13 DEC 2012</stdate>
        <endate>13 DEC 2012</endate>
        <advdate>19 DEC 2012</advdate>
        <dbdate> F40LA1C   </dbdate>
        <sname>N SINGLETON JG</sname>
        <acdesc>OVERDRAFT AAA</acdesc>
        <totfees>0</totfees>
        <discount>0</discount>
        <netfees>0</netfees>
        <clrdbal>93101200001034</clrdbal>
        <allowrte>0</allowrte>
        <discrte>0</discrte>
        <allowtot>0</allowtot>
        <pcode>0000000</pcode>
        <drillnsc>0</drillnsc>
        <dialog>9</dialog>
        <numlines>1</numlines>
        <totlines>0</totlines>
        <bpcust>P</bpcust>
        <nfeeexpdte></nfeeexpdte>
        <feedata>
            <fcode></fcode>
            <feedets></feedets>
            <chrgtype></chrgtype>
            <dcode></dcode>
            <volume>0</volume>
            <rate>0</rate>
            <total>0</total>
            <drill></drill>
        </feedata>
        <grossnetfees>
            <fquarter>06 DEC 12    12 DEC 12</fquarter>
            <grsfee>611960</grsfee>
            <nfee>611960</nfee>
            <feedisc>0</feedisc>
        </grossnetfees>
        <grossnetfees>
            <fquarter>01 DEC 12    05 DEC 12</fquarter>
            <grsfee>64850</grsfee>
            <nfee>64850</nfee>
            <feedisc>0</feedisc>
        </grossnetfees>
        <grossnetfees>
            <fquarter>08 NOV 12    30 NOV 12</fquarter>
            <grsfee>15866</grsfee>
            <nfee>15866</nfee>
            <feedisc>0</feedisc>
        </grossnetfees>
        <grossnetfees>
            <fquarter>01 NOV 12    07 NOV 12</fquarter>
            <grsfee>636</grsfee>
            <nfee>616</nfee>
            <feedisc>20</feedisc>
        </grossnetfees>
        <totgrsfee>693312</totgrsfee>
        <totnetfee>693292</totnetfee>
    </Fees720>
</Response>
```

I'm thinking I need to do something along the lines of:

```
strFees720Transform = XSLTransformer.transform("mynewxsl.xsl", strFees720);
```

and transform the original xml into the new xml. Any advice on best way to do this please. Thanks

updated with method

```
    private String getServiceValue(String strXMLResponse, String strNode, String strService) throws ServletException{

    String strNodeValue = null;

    try{
        builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
        Document doc = builder.build(new InputSource(new StringReader(strXMLResponse)));

        Element root = doc.getRootElement();  
        Element rootchild = root.getChild(strService); 
        List rootchildren = rootchild.getChildren();

        for (int i=0;i <= rootchildren.size() -1;i++)  
        {  
            Element el = (Element) rootchildren.get(i);  

            if(el.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(strNode)){
                strNodeValue = el.getText();
            }
        }  

    } catch (Exception err) {
        logger.error(err.getMessage(), err);
        throw new ServletException(err.getMessage());
    }

    return strNodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual advice for "I want to make a few changes to my XML but keep most of it the same" questions is: start with an identity template (which copies the input to output verbatim), then add specific templates for the things you want to change.  The identity template looks like

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now to handle the `<Field>` elements you want to create a new element whose name is derived from an attribute of the original `Field`

```
<xsl:template match="Field">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Value/node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The `translate` function here will replace all upper-case letters with the equivalent lower-case, and also remove any underscores completely.

Finally for the `FEEDATA` and `GROSSNETFEES` you just need two simple templates

```
<xsl:template match="FEEDATA">
  <feedata>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </feedata>
</xsl:template>
<!-- and likewise for GROSSNETFEES -->
```

You could combine these two templates into one using the same `translate` trick if you prefer.

As for the actual mechanics of doing the transformation, you need to look at the [javax.xml.transform package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html).  Seeing as you have code already to parse an XML string into a JDOM tree and extract the element of interest, I would do the XSL transformation in there.  Create a single `Templates` instance at initialization time and store the reference somewhere

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslSource = new StreamSource(new File(....));
templates = tf.newTemplates(xslSource);
```

Now each time you need to do the transformation you can use this `templates`

```
try{
    builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
    Document doc = builder.build(new InputSource(new StringReader(strXMLResponse)));

    Element root = doc.getRootElement();  
    Element rootchild = root.getChild(strService); 
    List rootchildren = rootchild.getChildren();

    for (int i=0;i <= rootchildren.size() -1;i++)  
    {  
        Element el = (Element) rootchildren.get(i);  

        if(el.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(strNode)){
            // do the transformation
            Source s = new JDOMSource(el);
            StringWriter resultWriter = new StringWriter();
            Result r = new StreamResult(resultWriter);
            templates.newTransformer().transform(s, r);
            return resultWriter.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just updated my question. I have included a method already in the code getServiceValue(). I'm just wondering if I can use this to perform what I require or are you suggesting I create a new stylesheet and do XSLTransformer.transform("mynewxsl.xsl", strFees720); ? Thanks again

Comment: @topcat3 I've added a bit more detail

Comment: Thanks for update. Is templates a String in this case? I was thinking to feed in the xsl as a string e.g. String myStrXsl = "<?xml vers ....."; and then do strFees720Transform = XSLTransformer.transform(myStrXsl, strFees720); but it obviously doesn't like the string in that format. I'll try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @topcat3 `templates` is a `javax.xml.transform.Templates` - essentially a compiled representation of the stylesheet.  My suggestion would mean your code just parses and compiles the stylesheet once and caches it, rather than re-parsing the XSL every time you want to use it.

Comment: @topcat3 I guess this is probably how `org.jdom.transform.XSLTransformer` works internally, but then you have the extra step of turning the transformation result from a JDOM `Document` back into a string.  Using the TrAX API as in my example you can skip this step and transform directly to a string.

Comment: damn I might be out of my depth now. you modified code inside my method getServiceValue() . I'm not sure what I'm doing now. Thought this would be easy lol :(

Comment: Any chance I could send you the full java file as I'm finding it hard to integrate change?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21276/discussion-between-ian-roberts-and-topcat3)

Comment: unfortunately my chat is blocked. probably goes against the rules but any chance you could email me gregpentium [at] gmail . can offer something to. prob easier if you had full java file

Comment: I don't have chat. Is there a simple way I can use getServiceValue() method above to extract all values from the xml and put them into individual strings maybe. The goal is to get all the values out so I can then populate an open office doc that has bookmarks. thanks